# What is causing my for/if loop to return 'longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length' warning in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to produce vector (PA) from the conditions of two other vectors. The other vectors are both 1978 elements in length.

The vectors are taken from loading in an excel file and using 'x <- S1L1$PercentageCoverage' and 'y <- S1L1$FoldCount'.

I believe the code should be checking if each element in x is equal to or greater than 1, and if each element in y is equal to or greater than 70. If they both pass this check, it should add the value of the ith element in the x vector to PA. If either fail, it should add 0.

```
PresenceCollector <- function(x, y){

PA <- c() 
    
  for (i in 1:1978){
    if ((x[i] >= 1) && (y[i] >= 70)){
      PA <- c(PA, x[i])
    } else {
      PA < - c(PA, 0)
    }
  }
}
```

The PA vector remains 'null' even after running the code, and it returns a warning message saying 'There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)'. This returns

```
1: In PA < -c(PA, 0) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In PA < -c(PA, 0) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In PA < -c(PA, 0) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

and so on until it prints 50

Any help on how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: It should be `<-`, not `< -`

Comment: Do either of the vectors have missing values? You should not need to do this with a loop. Something like `PA <- ifelse((x >= 1) && (y >= 70), x, 0)` should do it.

Comment: @dcarlson Should be only one `&`: `PresenceCollector <- function(x, y){ifelse((x >= 1) & (y >= 70), x, 0)}`

Comment: The growing of the vector will also be slow. If you want to use a loop and not vectorize (which is your best option), at least allocate the full vector before the loop since you now the size of it

Comment: @MaxHesselbarth I don’t understand what that means, how do I allocate a full vector?

Comment: First create an empty vector with the same length as the loop using `PA <- numeric(1978)`. Then, instead of growing the vector, just insert the values using `PA[i] <- x[i]` or  `PA[i] <- 0`. This is normally way faster than growing a vector. Also, since the vector is filled with zeros anyhow you wouldn't even need to `else` part. However, vectorization should be even fast than this as mentioned by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The vectors are taken from loading in an excel file and using 'x <- S1L1$PercentageCoverage' and 'y <- S1L1$FoldCount'."

It looks like you have S1L1 as a dataframe with PercentageCoverage and FoldCount columns and want to create a new column PA when PercentageCoverage >= 1 and FoldCount>=70, then PA should be PercentageCoverage else 0, correct?

```
S1L1$PA <- ifelse(S1L1$PercentageCoverage>=1 & S1L1$FoldCount>=70, S1L1$PercentageCoverage, 0)
```

Comment: So I need to get the FoldCount number for all the samples that have +70 coverage and +1 fold count. I then have another column called length which I will need to divide the fold count by, if it passes the initial checks.

Comment: I should add, thank you very much for helping! This was a very useful answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Here a very short solution:

```
function(x, y){
    x * (x >= 1 & y >= 70)
}
```

Pay attention to the parenthesis. In there a boolean value is created, i.e. `1`s or `0`s, and these are then multiplied with x.